# Hover doesn't execute

Tags: html, css

In SO when i hover over a tag i got a new div displayed like that

[image]

But when i check hover option in chrome i got nothing diplayed :

[image]

Can somebody explain me why ?

Comment: It's not a CSS hover... it's obviously made with JavaScript.

Comment: but how we can made stuff like CSS hover with JS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but how we can made stuff like CSS hover with JS

You can use the [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseover) and [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseout) events.

But be aware that those events bubble, so once the mouse has entered your target, if it enters a descendant of the target, it will fire your `mouseover` listener again.

If you want to avoid that, you can also use [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseleave), which don't bubble.

Comment: yes in this case `mouseenter` will be the best. Thanks @Oriol